# java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.breatheeasy.userinterface.viewmodels.MainViewModel

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewmodel

So i've started to get the following error on a Fragment and ViewModel that was previously working fine

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.breatheeasy.userinterface.viewmodels.MainViewModel
```

The code for the ViewModel in question is

```
class MainViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
private val mainRepository: MainRepository) : ViewModel() {

val runsSortedByDate = mainRepository.getAllRunsByDate()

fun insertRun (run : Run) = viewModelScope.launch {
    mainRepository.insertRun(run)
}
```

The code for the fragment is below. I've taken out alot of internal code except for where the app crashes when the instance of the ViewModel is asked for in the onViewCreated method

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class RunFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_run), EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks {

private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    viewModel.runsSortedByDate.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        runAdapter.submitList(it)
    })

}
}
```

Like I was said this was running fine until I added in another fragment with its own view model, but it doesn't appear that this error has any relation to this new fragment and view model as they are only called when I click on the relevant option in the bottom nav. I'm not even getting this far, the app is crashing straight away as it opens by default on the fragment shown above.

Many thanks

Comment: how do you providing this private val mainRepository: MainRepository dependency to MainViewModel?

Comment: `class MainRepository @Inject constructor(val runDAO: RunDAO) {

    suspend fun insertRun(run: Run) = runDAO.insertRun(run)
    suspend fun deleteRun(run: Run) = runDAO.deleteRun(run)

    fun getAllRunsByDate() = runDAO.getAllRunsByDate()

}`

Edit: Not sure how to get the code formatted correctly in comment but this is the MainRepository

Comment: can you update your questions with full dagger flow ?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. Do you mean show the relevant Hilt module class and where it is used ?